# focus with delay in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

i want when i clicked on textBox textBox will be focused with delay .
now when i set a function in onFocus() attribute with setTimeOut it will focus first then rest of code runs and that is not what i want.
i want to focus with delay and my code doesn't work!!

```
<input type="tel" id="PhoneInput" placeholder="phone number" onFocus="focusDelay()"/>
```

this function first focus on textBox then run setTimeout

```
function focusDelay()
{
    setTimeout(function(){
        $('#PhoneInput').focus();
    },4000);
}
```

Comment: That sounds **very** irritating for the user.

Answer (score 0):

When you get the event, it's *already* focussed the element. You need to unfocus (blur) it, and then focus it later. When you're focussing it on purpose, you need a flag to tell your code that it's okay to allow the focus to happen. Something like this (I've reduced the delay):

```js
var focussing = 0;
function focusDelay()
{
    if (!focussing) {
        var $input = $('#PhoneInput');
        $input.blur();
        setTimeout(function(){
            ++focussing;
            $input.focus();
            --focussing;
        }, 1000);
    }
}
```

```html
<input type="tel" id="PhoneInput" placeholder="phone number" onFocus="focusDelay()"/>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

I tend to use counter flags rather than boolean flags for this sort of thing, though in this particular case a boolean would probably work.